# $[0,\infty]$ valued measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

I have a question about measure theory.

Let $(X,\mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and $f$ be a $[0,\infty]$ valued $\mathcal{M}$ measurable function on $X$.

Is there $a_{k} \ge 0, A_{k} \in \mathcal{M}$ s.t. $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}1_{A_{k}}$, $A_{k} \cap A_{l}=\emptyset$ ($k \neq l$) ?

Since $f$ is $\mathcal{M}$ measurable, there exists $f_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{m^{(n)}}a_{k}^{(n)}1_{A_{k}^{(n)}}$ $A_{k}^{(n)} \cap A_{l}^{(n)}=\emptyset$ ($k \neq l$)  such that $f_{n}(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in X$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general no: simple functions are dense but you cannot "hold fixed" the value on $A_1$ as you increase the number of sets. This is much like how polynomials are dense in the continuous functions on a compact interval, and yet not every continuous function has a power series.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understood.